# Installing Git on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

How can I install Git on Eclipse? I found tutorials on http://cho.hapgoods.com/wordpress/?p=159 but there was said that "You should then see the eight Eclipse projects 'org.spearce.something.'" I don't see those eight projects.

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you have?

Answer (score 38):

Just add http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates to your Eclipse update manager.

Answer (score 20):

Do you have Egit installed yet? If not, go to Window->Preferences->Install/Updates->Available Software Sites. Click on add and paste this link http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

For Name, you can just put "EGit". After you have EGit installed, follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html) tutorial. It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 14):

Checkout this tutorial [Eclipse install Git plugin – Step by Step installation instruction](http://agile-qa-quality-assurance-software-testing-automation-blog.com/eclipse-install-git-plugin-step-by-step-installation-instruction/)

---

Eclipse install Git plugin – Step by Step installation instruction

Step 1) Go to: http://eclipse.org/egit/download/ to get the plugin repository location.

Step 2.) Select appropriate repository location. In my case its http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

Step 3.) Go to Help > Install New Software

Step 4.) To add repository location, Click Add. Enter repository name as “EGit Plugin”. Location will be the URL copied from Step 2. Now click Ok to add repository location.

Step 5.) Wait for a while and it will display list of available products to be installed. Expend “Eclipse Git Team Provider” and select “Eclipse Git Team Provider”. Now Click Next

Step 6.) Review product and click Next.

Step 7.) It will ask you to Accept the agreement. Accept the agreement and click Finish.

Step 8.) Within few seconds, depending on your internet speed, all the necessary dependencies and executable will be downloaded and installed.

Step 9.) Accept the prompt to restart the Eclipse.

Your Eclipse Git Plugin installation is complete.

To verify your installation.

Step 1.) Go to Help > Install New Software

Step 2.) Click on Already Installed and verify plugin is installed.

Answer (score 10):

egit was included in Indigo (2011) and should be there in all future Eclipse versions after that.

Just go to ![(Help->Install New Software)]

Then Work with: --All Available Sites--

Then type egit underneath and wait (may take a while) !
Then click the checkbox and install.

Answer (score 6):

I made an installation guide for Egit on Eclipse so I thought I would share it.

1. INSTALL EGIT plugin in eclispe which is pretty easy. If EGit is missing in your Eclipse installation, you can install it via the Eclipse Update Manager via: Help → Install new Software. EGit can be installed from the following URL: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates
   Under Eclipse Git Team Provider, tick ONLY "Eclipse EGit" and then download the plugin.
2. CONNECT TO YOUR LOCAL REPOSITORY. I right clicked on the project, selected "team > share project" and then ticked "use or create repository"
3. GIT IGNORE. Mark the "bin" folder as "ignored by Git", either by right-clicking on it and selecting Team > Ignore or by creating a .gitignore file. My file was generated for me, I just had to make it visible. Here's how in eclipse: In your package explorer, pull down the menu and select "Filters ...". You can adjust what types of files are shown/hidden there.
4. IDENTIFY YOURSELF. Click Preferences > Team > Git > Configuration and make sure your name & email are there so we know which user committed/pushed what.

NOW YOU ARE READY TO ADD/COMMIT/PUSH/PULL files with the plugin!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of installing the Git plugin in Eclipse

1. Installing through Help -> Install New Software..., then add the location http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/
2. Installing through Help -> Eclipse Marketplace..., then type **Egit** and installing it.

Both methods may need you to restart Eclipse in the middle. For the step by step guide on installing and configuring Git plugin in Eclipse, you can also refer to [Install and configure git plugin in Eclipse](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1539420590-Install-and-configure-git-plugin-in-Eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

It's Very Easy To Install By Following Below Steps In Eclipse JUNO version

Help-->Eclipse Marketplace-->Find: beside Textbox u can type "Egit"-->select Egit-git team provider intall button-->follow next steps and finally click finish

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of Eclipse you are using, but others have already posted good answers for modern versions of Eclipse. Unfortunately one of my legacy projects requires Eclipse Europa; the [old EGit project homepage](https://code.google.com/p/egit/wiki/OldProjectHomePage) states the following:

> The plugin only works on Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede) or newer. Eclipse 3.3 (Europa) is not supported anymore. Since the plugin is still very much work-in-progress we want to take advantage of new platforms features to facilitate progress.

So I guess I'm SOL - back to the graphical GitHub client for me! Lucky it's a legacy project.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this link:
http://download.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates

1)Go to Help-> Install new Software

2)Click on Add...

3)Name: eGit
  Location:http://download.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates

4)Click on OK

5)Accept the licence.

You are good to go